# How to write a method that uses global variable in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm currently working on my first Svelte project, and have run into a problem with recyclability of code.

I have a few components that use the same functionality, so of course I want to put the shared functionality in a file where my components can import methods from.

I have run into a problem where the methods that I import does not know about variables that are attached to my component.

Minimal, working example (code below);

https://svelte.dev/repl/59170f8e82274215a0b64692c3e4613c?version=3.55.0

In this example App import the `transformName` method, but does not know about `name`. When looking at the two components, `Greetings` and `Goodbye` you can see that I have made the exact same method in both components which works as expected.

App.svelte

```
    <script>
    import Greeting from './Greeting.svelte'
    import Goodbye from './Goodbye.svelte'
    import {transformName} from './transformName.js'
    
    let name = 'globalName';
    </script>
    <Greeting name="world"/>
    <Goodbye name="my friend"/>
    <h1>Hello {transformName()}!</h1>
```

transformName.js

```
export function transformName() {
    return name.toUpperCase();
}
```

Goodbye.svelte

```
<script>
    export let name;
    
    function transformName() {
        return name.toUpperCase();
    }
</script>
<div>
    Goodbye {transformName()}
</div>

Greeting.svelte
```

Greeting.svelte

```
<script>
    export let name;
    
    function transformName() {
        return name.toUpperCase();
    }
</script>
<div>
    Hello, {transformName()}
</div>
```

I've thought of just taking in the name as a parameter to the method, but that feels redundant and I would have to refactor a lot of code for this approach to work.

So, my question is; Is it possible to write a method that can be in a separate file and still know about variables on the component it is imported into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to pass a variable to the method. I've changed a litle your REPL and you could try this new https://svelte.dev/repl/6d19efc4316b483eb64d2a00262baf1d?version=3.55.0

In resume, in transformName.js:

```
export function transformName(name) {
  return name.toUpperCase();
}
```

And App.svelte:

```
<h1>Hello {transformName(name)}!</h1>
```